# Mediawiki creates custom group

Tags: permissions, mediawiki

I have a very confusing problem with my mediawiki at the moment. I was about to set up some new permissions in the localsettings.php and included the [Namespace Protection](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgNamespaceProtection) plugin. But for some reason, I now have a new group where I can give permissions to the users which is called "Benutzer". It's the german translation for Users but i have no clue why it was created. Here a link to my actual localsettings.php: [Link](http://pastebin.com/GXXPBW5Z)
When I look at the userrighs list, I also have to groups named "Benutzer". One is created by mediawiki and the other one I don't know...

---

Well, that wasn't the problem, but I fixed it now. In the localsettings.php, I wrote "$wgGroupPermissions['User']" instead of "$wgGroupPermissions['user']" so mediawiki thought i wanted to create a new group, and the big problem was, it localized it also, so I didn't saw my mistake.
But thanks for trying to help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When displayed on special pages, the names of user groups [are localized](https://translatewiki.net/wiki/MediaWiki%3aGroup-user/de), so if your language i German, and the user group is called `Benutzer`, then everything is working as it should.

- [User group message documentation](https://translatewiki.net/wiki/MediaWiki%3aGroup-user/qqq)